# egrep part required for svn hook script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a pre commit hook script to Enforcing tag naming convention like `< application>_ < project >_ < version>_ < iteration>` this using a shell script can anyone guide me to a doc/link something which I can go through and can create one. I have already gone through many links but didn't work for me

I am trying something like this

```
ERROR=$SVNLOOK changed $REPO -t $REV |$EGREP "^A.+?/([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\1-[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?-(dev|rc[0-9]+|final)/.*$" |$WC -l


#!/bin/sh

REPO="$1"
REV="$2"
ERROR=0
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook

AWK=/bin/awk
GREP=/bin/grep
EGREP=/bin/egrep
WC=/usr/bin/wc


ERROR=`$SVNLOOK changed $REPO -t $REV |$EGREP -i "^A.+/tags/.+$" |$WC -l`
if [ $ERROR -ne 0 ]
then

  ERROR=`$SVNLOOK changed $REPO -t $REV |$EGREP "^A.+?/([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\1-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?-(dev|rc[0-9]+|final)/.*$" |$WC -l`
  if [ $ERROR -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Tag isn't in the correct format" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
```

**Example**: FV_SSE-MAY-14_2.1.0_03

Where: Application = FV Project = SSE-MAY-14 Version = 2.1.0 Iteration = 03

Comment: I really have no clue what exactly you are trying to ask... Can you give an example?

Comment: Example:
 
FV_SSE-MAY-14_2.1.0_03
 
Where:
 
Application = FV
Project = SSE-MAY-14
Version = 2.1.0
Iteration = 03

Comment: I hope this throw some light

Comment: I agree with Bernhard. In its current form your question is hardly usable. If you want help with `grep` then give example input like `echo foo | grep ...`.

Comment: I am pasting my script
hope this helps

Comment: All we need is the string you will grep and your desired output. Without that we can't help.

Comment: @terdon Took me some time to notice but the OP has already given example input ;-)

Comment: need help with grep part guyz :)
any more info is required let me know
thnx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
echo FV_SSE-MAY-14_2.1.0_03 | 
  LC_ALL=C egrep "^[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-[0-9]?[0-9]_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]+$"
```

Comment: I am trying like this now, `ERROR=`$SVNLOOK changed $REPO -t $REV |$EGREP "^A.+?/([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\"^[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+-[0-9]?[0-9]_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]+$" |$WC -l` `